# Tail command -f on all files excluding a file

Tags: bash

I want to run tail -f command on all the file in a directory except one file in that directory.  Can somebody suggest me a way of doing it thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tail multiple files in CentOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908548/tail-multiple-files-in-centos)

Comment: @BillKarwin: This is not about unfriendly output but about excluding a single file from list of arguments; Wildcard with exclusion.

Answer (score 12):

```
       ls | grep -v unwanted | xargs tail -f
```

Comment: Or if you want to avoid [parsing the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), you can use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name 'file_to_exclude' -print0 | xargs -0 tail -f`

Comment: Also, if you're allergic to xargs, use backtick syntax. ```tail -f `ls|grep -v unwanted` ```

Comment: @ SF You can put backticks inside triple backticks like this ```This is a backtick ` in code```

Comment: That did the trick, so this is just for my future reference `ls | grep -v facebook-business-extension.log | grep -v stock_import.log | grep -v cache.log | grep -v Watchlog-cron.log | grep -v cron.log | grep -v system.log | xargs tail -f` to exclude few files from tail.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `exec` flag with `find` to give you a nice cohesive one liner:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name unwanted.txt -exec tail -f {} +`

You can also play around with the `-maxdepth` flag if you want to go more than the current directory in depth or omit it completely if you wanted to recurse through the current directory and all sub directories.

You can also add other excluded files by using the `-a` flag like so:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name unwanted.txt -a -type f ! -name unwanted2.txt -exec tail -f {} +
```

However that could get a little tedious for an extended amount of files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash's [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob), e.g.:

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ ll
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x 2 foo foo 4.0K Sep 16 10:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 foo foo 4.0K Sep 16 10:14 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo    2 Sep 16 10:15 one
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo    2 Sep 16 10:15 three
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo    2 Sep 16 10:15 two

$ ll !(three)
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo    2 Sep 16 10:15 one
-rw-r--r-- 1 foo foo    2 Sep 16 10:15 two

$ tail *
==> one <==
1

==> three <==
3

==> two <==
2

$ tail !(three)
==> one <==
1

==> two <==
2
```